# jQuery Mobile: how to do page transition after page is fully loaded into DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Single-Page Applications, Query Mobile 1.4.5 & jQuery v1.11.1

Is this possible that after click on **Page 1** url it should wait till page 1 to load full into DOM after it load, page transition should happened

because my page 1 have some ajax which request some time to load

```
<div data-role="page" id="menu">
    Menu
    <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">Page 1</a></br>
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Page 2</a></br>
</div>      
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    ...some text.
    <div id="articles_list">
        some data from ajax...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you absolutely need that, use buttons instead of anchors (or anchors with void href) & change page by code in ajax complete. But, why you should need that?

Comment: After clicking on Page 1 url it shows page 1 with …. Some text at top  and remaining bottom page is blank where ajax is there(ajax required some time to load). So I want page should load after ajax is fully loaded.

Comment: Blocking actions are annoying... here my proposal: 1) if you click a menu entry and your page is transitioning immediately, there is IMHO a better user experience. 2) then, your page1 is showing the loader spinner, telling you that the list entries are about to load. 3) after data arrival, close the spinner and invoke `refresh` and `updatelayout` to tell JQM to nicely restyle the list and the page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely need to wait until your data is fully loaded, then you can navigate by code. Just use a button instead of an anchor.

In the example below, i'm chaining two ajax requests to build a simple list of albums. After successfully retrieval, the list is sorted and the page content is restyled:

```js
function gotoPage1() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $.mobile.loading("show");
    }
  }).then(function(users) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
      method: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(albums) {
        $("#articles_list").empty();
        $.each(albums, function(index, album) {
          album.userName = $.grep(users, function(user, index) {
            return (user.id == album.userId);
          })[0].name;
        });
        albums.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.userName.localeCompare(b.userName);
        });
        $.each(albums, function(index, album) {
          $("#articles_list").append("<li>"+album.userName+"<p><strong>"+album.title+"</strong></p></li>");
        });
        $("#articles_list").listview({
          autodividers: true,
          inset: true
        }).listview("refresh");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page1", {transition: "slide"});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="menu">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" onclick="gotoPage1();">Page 1</button>
        <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Page 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>      
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <h3>...some text.</h3>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="articles_list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <h3>...some text.</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        some other data from ajax...
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```