# Jquery - $.mobile.changePage is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change pages on in my project. I have two divs containing information and they each have a data-role of "page". In addition, they both have ids. On my js file I have a simple onclick event that calls a function that then uses the

```
          $.mobile.changePage("#2");
```

To go from my first div to my second div. The only problem is whenever I try to change the page I am getting an error:

```
          Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changePage' of undefined
```

I have already searched on other peoples posts on stack overflow and haven't found anything that can help me. Here is some of my code:

global.html

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
    maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/jquery.mobile- 
    1.4.5.css">


    <script src="js/global.js"></script>

    <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/p5.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="1" style="background-color: #56f0b1;">
         <button id ="startGame" type="button">Start Game</button>
   </div>

   <div data-role="page" id="2" style="background-color: #56f0b1;">
         <h2>Page 2 </h2>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

global.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#startGame").on("click",getToNextPage);
 });

 function getToNextPage(){
     $.mobile.changePage("#2");
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to include the jQuery core library before jQuery Mobile. See [Mobile Page Structure](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages/#Mobilepagestructure).

Comment: Your jquery library needs to go before the mobile library

Comment: I believe it already is. I have the <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> before the  <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

Comment: What I mean is, in the code you provided, `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js` is included before `jquery.min.js`. Those two need to be loaded in the reverse order.

Comment: Oh, in that case, is there a reason you're loading two jQuery versions?

Comment: Im quite new to this so i wasn't sure if it made a difference or not and if it does which version to keep? And when i tried switching like you had proposed my page wouldnt load

Comment: I might try loading the scripts in this order: "jquery.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js, p5.min.js, global.js".

Comment: Unfortunately that does load the page but all of my divs are everywhere all, all my divs are showing instead of the first one showing

Comment: Please be aware that mixing jQuery-UI and jQueryMobile is an advanced topic, both libraries have its own widgets and You will experience some unexpected behavior until You are doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the core jQuery library must be loaded before jQuery Mobile.
In your code, it seems you're loading two jQuery versions and one of them is loaded after jQuery Mobile.

Also, according to comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234553/uncaught-typeerror-a-split-is-not-a-function-pagecontainer), the page IDs should not be only numeric.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#startGame").on("click", getToNextPage);
});

function getToNextPage() {
  $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="page" id="page1" style="background-color: #56f0b1;">
  <button id="startGame" type="button">Start Game</button>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" style="background-color: #56f0b1;">
  <h2>Page 2 </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright and in that Hierarchy where would I define my global.js file?

Comment: I would put it last, after `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js`.